# Is it possible in c++ in an abstract class constructor to use a pointer of this abstract class as parameter?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, tree, abstract-class

I've got an abstract class that represents an item of a tree. As this class already inherits from another (not abstract) class I want to use the same structure in the constructor as the  base class:

```
class TreeItem //already given class
{
public:
    TreeItem(TreeItem *parent = 0);
    ...
};

class AbstractTreeItem : public TreeItem //class with some abstract methods
{
public:
    AbstractTreeItem(TreeItem *parent = 0);
    ...
};
```

But I want to assure that all classes which will inherit of my abstract class only have children of AbstractTreeItem, too. Therefore I would like to use a constructor like the following:

```
class AbstractTreeItem : public TreeItem
{
public:
    AbstractTreeItem(AbstractTreeItem *parent = 0);
    ...
};
```

And this is not possible as AbstractTreeItem is an abstract class. So is there a possiblity to achieve this in another way?

Comment: Can you explain why you say that is "not possible?" I can't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: Looks fine to me. What's the problem?

Comment: I think there is some problem with your design.. Why you need to inherit TreeItem using an abstract class. I think you can you do it as Creating AbstractTreeItem and inherit it using TreeItem...

Comment: Oh no, you're right. The error ("variable type 'GraphicsItem' is an abstract class") was caused by a bad accidental mistake in my file. And the error message made me think this is not possible. Thanks a lot for your answers! They led me to the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> “this [using an `AbstractTreeItem*` argument] is not possible as AbstractTreeItem is an abstract class”

is incorrect.

I.e. there is no technical problem.

There does appear to be a design level problem, but that's a different kettle of fish.

Answer (score 0):

So, you probably will have an non-abstract class:

```
class NonAbstractTreeItem : public AbstractTreeItem
{
public:
    NonAbstractTreeItem(AbstractTreeItem *parent = 0): AbstractTreeItem(parent) {
       ...
    }
    ...
};
```

that will be calling the AbstractTreeItem constructor.

If you want to underline that the constructor  is only intended to be called from a child class, you can make it protected:

```
class AbstractTreeItem : public TreeItem
{
protected:
    AbstractTreeItem(AbstractTreeItem *parent = 0);
    ...
};
```